# GCP VM instance not showing LESS keys as GCP editing instance metadata?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, gcp

authorized_keys is missing AFTER I add my ssh key to an instance in GCP so then I connect via browser and authorized_keys is generated with 1. 'TWO keys'.  I then click edit on instance and I see 2. 'FOUR keys' and then global ssh I see 3. 'ONE key'

I can't figure out how to add my key globally OR on the instance.  How in the world is GCP work here.  I thought I could add key, click save, but that seems to delete authorized keys rather than generate it :( .  I have no idea what is going on here.